# In strapi, how to filter richtext markdown field?

Tags: strapi, nuxt-strapi

I want to filter on the rich text markdown field.

I'm able to search on the field but Strapi API also returns results that match with markdown syntax.

Link, if I search for `###` then API return all the articles which have the `h3` tag in the rich text field. It should not filter on markdown syntax.

Is there any way I can achieve this behavior?